# Lighting CSS search icon

Tags: lightning-web-components

We have a lwc service console page. Where we have some custom and standard components arranged. Now while testing we found an issue the search icon from standard knowledge components is displays on the top on lwc custom popup components. Do any one have fix on this issue. The issue is not for a component it happens for all the components which popups on the knowledge component.

Img 1
[image: Img 1]

Img 2
[image: Img 2]

Img 3
[image: Img 3]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting its CSS position to absolute and align it in relation to its parent component/div
e.g

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
```